# Generic validation on input

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to write a generic method to validate all the UIControls like NSTextField, NSTextView, etc. If any mandatory field is empty, a consolidated one alert should be shown with the first control as focused/first responder.

I have implemented something like this:

```
-(NSInteger)lengthAfterTrimmingSpaces:(NSString *)string{
    return [[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] length];
}


-(NSDictionary *)createWarningMessageForMandatoryFields:(NSArray *)uiObjects{

    NSMutableString *warningString=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Enter "];
    id firstInvalidatedControl=nil;

    for (NSDictionary *object in uiObjects) {
        NSString *key=[object allKeys][0];
        id control=object[key];
        if ([control isKindOfClass:[NSTextField class]]) {
            if ([self lengthAfterTrimmingSpaces:[control stringValue]]==0){
                [warningString appendString:key];
                [warningString appendString:@", "];

                if (firstInvalidatedControl==nil) {
                    firstInvalidatedControl=control;
                }
            }
        }
        else if ([control isKindOfClass:[NSTextView class]]) {
            if ([self lengthAfterTrimmingSpaces:[control string]]==0){
                [warningString appendString:key];
                [warningString appendString:@", "];
                if (firstInvalidatedControl==nil) {
                    firstInvalidatedControl=control;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (firstInvalidatedControl==nil) {
        return @{@"warningString":@"Success"};
    }
    else{

        warningString =[[warningString substringToIndex:[warningString length] - 2]mutableCopy];
        return @{@"warningString":warningString, @"control":firstInvalidatedControl};
    }
}


-(BOOL)validateMandatoryFields{
    NSMutableArray *uiObjects=[NSMutableArray array];

    [uiObjects addObject:@{@"Segment Name":self.segmentName}];
    [uiObjects addObject:@{@"Code":self.code}];
    [uiObjects addObject:@{@"Desciption":self.description}];

    NSDictionary *warningAndControl=[self createWarningMessageForMandatoryFields:uiObjects];
    if ([warningAndControl[@"warningString"] isEqualToString:@"Success"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else{
        [[self window] makeFirstResponder:warningAndControl[@"control"]];
        NSRunAlertPanel(@"Warning", warningAndControl[@"warningString"], @"OK", nil, nil);
        return NO;
    }
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%d",[self validateMandatoryFields]);
}
```

Now I want to make it even more generic, as for each kind I am doing class introspection and then then retrieving the value ( stringValue/string etc).

Also any other suggestions for this is appreciated.

Comment: What you are asking for is a regular programmer's task. Move `appendString` etc block to a separate function/method at least. Or separate entire `isKindOfClass` level by passing control, required class, string-retrieving-block/selector, warning string, key, and `firstInvalidatedControl` as arguments.

Comment: Single method that will take more arguments, not few more methods. `[self processControl:control requiredClass:[NSTextField class] warningString:warningString key:key firstInvalidatedControl:& firstInvalidatedControl stringValueSelector:@selector(stringValue)]`. Or, if you're not against bindings, better approach may be to bind controls to viewController's properties and test them properties (and forget about controls at all).

Answer (score 0):

You're basing logic (deciding if there was an error) on the content of strings that will be presented to the user. You shouldn't. Instead, base the logic on the keys (`control`) as they are immutable. Together with this you should use `NSLocalizedString` to future proof the code for reuse.

For the introspection, I'd consider putting these methods into a utility class and adding a number of categories into that class also. The categories would add a single method to each `NSControl` subclass with the aim being to allow you to get their `stringValue` by always calling a method with the same name. For `NSTextField` you wouldn't need a category. For `NSTextView` the category would be:

```
@implementation NSTextView (MyStringValue)

- (NSString *)stringValue
{
    return [self string];
}

@end
```

Your code should still verify that the class responds to the `stringValue` selector, if it doesn't it can't be validated.

Answer (score 0):

Binding controls to view controller's properties may help.

```
@interface MyViewController

@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *string;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSDate *date;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSNumber *number;

@end
```

Now you bind control values to File Owner's `string` / `date` / `number` properties.

```
@implementation MyViewController

- (void)testForm
{
    for (NSString *key in @[@"string", @"date", @"number"]) {
        id value = [self valueForKey:key];
        if (value == nil || [value isEqual:@""] || [value isEqual:@(0.0)] || ...) {
            // empty field
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that you work with real data here, i.e. if you have date/number field, you do not check sanity of it's stringValue (that is formatter's job), but of already converted/formatted value.